# Data Persistence using shared preferences

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am a rookie programmer with this being my first real attempt at coding an app. I am looking to code an app then can be triggered remotely via Bluetooth to send a text message to a preset contact in case of emergency.
However, I am stuck at the use of the package shared preferences, where I'm trying to save the contact data to the app for use during a relaunch. I have followed tutorials and ended up with a code with no critical errors, per Android Studio but the data is still not saved. Please advise accordingly.

```
import 'package:contact_picker/contact_picker.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(Whican());
}

class Whican extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WhicanState createState() => _WhicanState();
}

class _WhicanState extends State<Whican> {
  final ContactPicker _contactPicker = new ContactPicker();
  Contact _contact;
  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();
  }

  getData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _contact = prefs.get(_contact.toString());
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Center(child: const Text('WHICAN APP')),
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
          ),
          drawer: Drawer(
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: <Widget>[
                DrawerHeader(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orangeAccent),
                  child: Text(
                    'Settings',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 24,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.message),
                  title: Text('Update Emergency Message'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.contacts),
                  title: Text('Update Emergency Contact'),
                  onTap: () async {
                    Contact contact = await _contactPicker.selectContact();
                    SharedPreferences prefs =
                        await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                    setState(() {
                      _contact = contact;
                      prefs.setString(_contact.toString(), _contact.toString());
                    });
                    print(contact); //TODO: Remove this
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.bluetooth),
                  title: Text('Connect Bluetooth'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.help),
                  title: Text('Help'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.feedback),
                  title: Text('Feedback'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: Row(children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Card(
                color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.contacts,
                        size: 60.0,
                      ),
                      Text(_contact.toString()),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not have this `SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();` in one place instead of calling it twice? And also call `prefs.setString(...)` outside the `setState((){})`

Answer (score 0):

According to my investigation the first problem occurs when getData method inside initState is called. Here your field _contact is always null. So in fact this line of code `_contact = prefs.get(_contact.toString());` returns null every time.

Besides you cannot simply save Contact object that way: `prefs.setString(_contact.toString(), _contact.toString());` This code will save string value "Instance of 'Contact'" in shared preferences under key "Instance of 'Contact'". If you would like to save Contact object in shared preferences, you could consider converting it to JSON, then saving JSON as string value. Please note this is just one of the possible solutions, maybe you are able to save contact ID or something inside shared preferences and use it to get contact via ContactPicker. However, saving parsed contact code could look like:

```
Contact contact = await _contactPicker.selectContact();
String contactJson = parseContactToJsonString(contact);
prefs.setString("savedContact", contactJson);
```

And here is the loading code:

```
String contactJson = prefs.get("savedContact");
_contact = convertJsonToContact(contactJson);
```

Of course parseContactToJsonString and convertJsonToContact are methods which you should implement yourself. You could find info about JSON serialization for example here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json